# How can I compare elements in same list and append to other list ? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append, compare

I want to compare elements in same list and append to other list but I have some problems.
For example:

```py
a=[3,4,21,36,10,28,35,5,24,42]
c=[]
```

I want to do this:
`4>3` append to other list.
`21>4` append to other list.
`36>21` append to other list.
`28>10` but don't append this to other list because 36 is bigger than 28.
The result should be `c=[4,21,36,42]`.

I tried this code:

```py
b=0
d=1
while len(a)>b and len(a)>d:
    if a[d]>a[b]:
        c.append(a[d])

    b+=1
    d+=1
```

But it instead gives me:
`c=[4, 21, 36, 28, 35, 24, 42]`

Comment: If you merely want to append elements that are bigger than their previous element, then `c=[4, 21, 36, 28, 35, 24, 42]` is the correct answer...

Comment: You also need to compare a[d] to c[-1] to check whether the current element of a is larger than the last element of c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
a=[3,4,21,36,10,28,35,5,24,42]
c = []

for x in range(1,len(a)):
    count = 0
    for y in range(x):
        if a[x] > a[y]:
            count = count + 1
    if count == x:
        c.append(a[x])
print(c)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.It solved my problem but I didn't understand situation.Why did you use if count == x:
        c.append(a[x]) ?

Comment: if x and count is same means every value before a[x] is lower.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate and check

```
currentList = [3,4,21,36,10,28,35,5,24,42]
newList = []
current_low = currentList[0]-1 # initialse current_low as [(first element of list) - 1]

for value in currentList:
    if value > current_low:
        newList.append(value)
        current_low = value

>>>print(newList)
[3, 4, 21, 36, 42]
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a moment to realize you want numbers that are less than ALL previous numbers, not just the number before it.

If you want to do this with a list comprehension, you could do:

```py
c = [a[i] for i in range(1,len(a)) if a[i] > max(a[:i])]
```

Result: `[4, 21, 36, 42]`

If, however, you changed your mind and decided you wanted numbers greater than their previous number, you could do:

```py
c = [j for (i,j) in filter(lambda x: x[0] < x[1], zip(a, a[1:]))]
```

Result: `[4, 21, 36, 28, 35, 24, 42]`